# Play sound on click on android

Tags: android

```
Button my_button = findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    my_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

// Here I want to play a simple WAV file.

        }
    });
```

From what I understand, you want to have your wav file in res/raw; so I created the raw folder and copied a simple 1-second test wav file into it. I haven't pasted any code here because I've tried about 15 different variations from stackoverflow contributors to try to get this little wav file to play. Can't find the file in raw, not sure how to reference it, etc.
What would be the simplest way to play that wave, especially including the path, as that seems to be one of my issues. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

After three hours, found this:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_test_sound);

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
mp.start();
```

I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks anyway folks :)

Comment: Do look at media player state diagram https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram. You have to free resource accordingly and prevent unnecessary crashes.

Comment: Gaurav Chauhan: I added a listener with mp.release();